# Are there still communities that eat roasted meat Seder night?

Tags: passover, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, meat

Okay, so we no longer eat a whole roasted lamb Seder night(s). The mishna says in some places the custom is to specifically eat roasted meat, and in others the custom is *not* to. That's basically what the Shulchan Aruch says as well, and then the Mishna Brurah and others say the standard Ashkenazic practice is *not* to eat dry-roasted meat.

Are there any communities (Sephardi, Edot Mizrah, Italian, ???) that still have the custom to *yes* eat dry-roasted meat?

Comment: Can you cite this mishna and shulchan arukh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/8136#42b) footnote 42 and 43 it brings sources that Yemenite and Italian communities still eat roasted meat on Pesach night.

In footnote 46 he also brings sources about Tripoli eating the Zeroa, but I'm not clear if they roast it or cook it.